# How to Validate using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a input field like Vehicle Registration Number,  how to validate using jquery this input below condtions:-

```
i) Min Size - 4 Characters
ii) Should contain atleast 3 Alpha characters
iii) First 2 Characters should be alpha

var registration=$("#add-car-registration").val();

if(registration==""){
$.alert({title:"Information",content:"Enter Registration Number"});
return false;           
}

if (registration.match('(.*?[a-zA-Z]){0,3}')) {
$.alert({title:"Information",content:"Minimum 2 alphabets"});   
return false;
}

if(registration.length<4){
$.alert({title:"Information",content:"Min 4 Characters Registration Number"});              
return false;           
}
```

Comment: Give a try from your side. Then we can correct it.

Comment: try reading the documentation https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

You cant do separate conditions, you should use `if`, `else if`, etc... to make the correct way, also you need to detect the submit event and block it if is not validated (not with return because return will stop everything). for example (note i changed your alerts into normal alerts to test it):

UPDATE: i improved the number validation to match the format (example: TG24 V 2234)

```
$(".myform").submit(function(e){ 

  var registration = $("#add-car-registration").val();
  var format1 = /(?=(?:.*?[A-Za-z]){2})/; //minimum 2 alphabets
  var format2 = /^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/; //numbers, alphabets and spaces

  if(registration==""){
    alert("Information\nEnter Registration Number");
    e.preventDefault();        
  }
  else if (!(format1.test(registration)) || !(format2.test(registration))){
    alert("Information\nMinimum 2 alphabets, numbers and spaces only");  
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else if(registration.length<4){
    alert("Information\nMin 4 Characters Registration Number");            
    e.preventDefault();     
  } 
  else{
    $(this).submit();
  }

});
```

You can test here: https://jsfiddle.net/cw0954sh/3/

Comment: Minimum 2 alphabets condition not working and also first two letters should be alphabet., hw to do solve it , plz help me.

Comment: i think your regular expression is not correct, i dont know how the Vehicle Registration Number structure, can you give me an example?

Comment: like this, TG24 V 2234

Comment: OK, i improved the code and tested with two regular expressions, i hope it helps you to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex to validate your input as the follow:

```
$(".myform").submit(function(e){
  var vrn = $("#vrn").val();
  if (vrn.length < 4) {
    alert("Min. 4 chars");
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (!vrn.match(/^[A-Z1-9]{2}/gi)) {
    alert("First 2 chars must be alpha");  
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (!vrn.match(/([A-Z1-9].*){3}/gi)) {
    alert("Atleast 3 chars must be alpha");  
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    alert('success')
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bc4og2/)